# pandas rolling window: Avoiding O(n^2) in for loops

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy

Given the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [np.random.randint(1, 100) for i in xrange(1000)]
df['B'] = [np.random.randint(1, 100) for i in xrange(1000)]
```

I would like to compute some statistics based on a rolling window:

- that has a 50% overlap
- within this window, I would like to break it into 10 smaller non-overlapping windows and compute statistics for each of the 10 windows and save this information to a list.

This is what I mean:

```
0 100
____________________
0 10
10 20
20 30
30 40
40 50
50 60
60 70
70 80
80 90
90 100
____________________
50 150
____________________
50 60
60 70
70 80
80 90
90 100
100 110
110 120
120 130
130 140
140 150
____________________
100 200
____________________
100 110
110 120
...
```

1. Take a window of size 100 data points.
2. Break that into a small window of 10 data points.
3. Compute statistics.
4. Back to 1: Move the window by 50%.
5. Repeat steps 2 and 3
6. Back to 1: ...

I have the following code that works.

```
def rolling_window(df, size=100):
    start = 0
    while start < df.count():
        yield start, start + size
        start += (size / 2)

stats = []

for start, end in windows(df['A']):
    step = 10
    time_range = np.arange(start, end + step, step)
    times = zip(time_range[:-1], time_range[1:])
    for t in times:
        s = t[0]
        e = t[1]
        this_drange = df.loc[s:e,'B'].max() - df.iloc[s:e,'B'].min()
        stats.append(this_drange)
```

**But the two `for loops` take 9 hours for 0.5 million rows. How do I modify the code such that it is really fast?** Is there a way to vectorize this?

I tried looking at `pd.rolling()` but I have no idea how to set it up such that there is a 50% overlap. Also, this is much more than just 50% overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some inspiration. I'm not sure it handles all edge cases correctly though..

```
def thing2(window=100, step=50, subwindow=10, substep=10):
    # Calculate stats for all possible subwindows
    rolled = df['B'].rolling(window=subwindow)
    stats = rolled.max() - rolled.min()
    # Only take the stats of complete subwindows
    stats = stats[subwindow-1:]

    # Collect the subwindow stats for every "macro" window
    idx, subidx = np.ogrid[:len(df)-window+1:step, :window:substep]
    linidx = (idx + subidx).ravel()
    return stats.iloc[linidx]
```